# How to change "LogonUserIdentity.Name" for debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to set or change the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` for debugging purpose? I tried changing it but it's read only:

> Error 10  Property or indexer 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Name' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

I try to proof if the user is member of a specific active directory group to remove items from the navigation menu. So I have to check the groups of the user, I can change the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` for debugging but with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` I'm reading the groups:

```
List<string> groups = new List<string>();
foreach (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference group in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
            groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a bit more context would be helpful. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @CelestialDragonofOsiris: Please see my edit

Comment: Well, since the Property is `readonly` you can't change it, but what you could do is assign the Value to a *local variable* first and then use it instead of using the Property directly, this way, you can edit it for debugging, when you need to.